# Docker-compose traefik PathPrefixStrip do not work correctly

Tags: docker, routes, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik

I've a problem who drive me mad, please help me.

I want to access all my apps from one free no-ip subdomain, so I think traefik can do that for me, I want to access all my apps like that:

```
 mysubdomain.no-ip.com/emby
 mysubdomain.no-ip.com/pydio
 mysubdomain.no-ip.com/adminer...
```

Here is my docker compose:

```
version: "2"
services:
  db:
    image: linuxserver/mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "test"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    volumes:
      - ./config/mariadb:/etc/mysql/
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=adminer"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/dbadmin"
      - "traefik.backend.port=8080"
    volumes:
      - ./config/adminer:/config
  emby:
    image: emby/embyserver:latest
    restart: always
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=emby"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/media"
      - "traefik.backend.port=8096"
    volumes:
      - ./config/emby:/config
  cloud:
    image: linuxserver/pydio:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGID: "1000"
      PUID: "1000"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=cloud"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/cloud"
      - "traefik.backend.port=443"
      - "traefik.protocol=https"
    volumes:
      - ./config/cloud:/config
      - ./data/test:/data
  organizr:
      image: lsiocommunity/organizr
      restart: always
      environment:
        PGID: "1000"
        PUID: "1000"
        TZ: "Europe/Paris"
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.backend=organizr"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/"
        - "traefik.backend.port=80"
      volumes:
        - ./config/organizr:/config
        - ./data/organizr:/data
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.3.3
    command: --web --docker --docker.domain=traefik --logLevel=DEBUG #-c /dev/null --web --docker --logLevel=INFO
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '8080:8080'
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./config/traefik/data:/data
      - ./config/traefik/sslcerts:/ssl
```

My traefik.toml

```
# defaultEntryPoints must be at the top because it should not be in any table below
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
InsecureSkipVerify = true

[web]
# Port for the status page
address = ":8080"

# Entrypoints, http and https
[entryPoints]

  # http should be redirected to https
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"

  # https is the default
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      CertFile = "/ssl/tls.crt"
      KeyFile = "/ssl/tls.key"
[retry]

# Enable ACME (Let's Encrypt): automatic SSL
# [acme]
# # caServer = "https://acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
# email = "test@gmail.com"
# storage = "acme.json" # or "traefik/acme/account" if using KV store
# entryPoint = "https"
# onDemand = false
# OnHostRule = true

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "localhost"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

So I have only 1 app who work like a charm: emby.

Adminer semms to work correctly, load css and others assets, but when I submit the form, it send me to localhost/server=db&username=test it should send me to localhost/dbadmin/server=db&username=test

When I access to localhost/cloud/ it load me a blank page, if I open console of Chrome:

```
pydio.material.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () pydio.boot.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () 
cloud:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: PydioBootstrap is not defined at cloud:18 pydio.material.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

In fact it try to load plugins from localhost/plugins and not from localhost/cloud/plugins ...
I see a lot of issue on github related to this but it seems to be corrected in 1.3.3 version, I try 1.3.3, latest...

Do pydio and adminer needs to support reverse-proxy?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

In traefik, PathPrefixStrip and redirects in the entrypoint [do not currently work together](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/1957). So if your request goes to http instead of https, you'll get an error.

In [my own demo](https://github.com/boxboat/traefik-tls), I just setup nginx on port 80 to send the redirect as a short term workaround until the above issue gets fixed.

Comment: I see that, but in my case, same problem if I replace the line       -./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml by by /dev/null:/traefik.toml, when I access to http://localhost/dbadmin and submit the form traefik redirect me to http://localhost/?server=db&username=test, it loose the prefixPathStrip too

Comment: That looks like an issue with your form redirect. I needs to redirect to a relative path if you want it to work through the proxy. Putting a `/` at the front of the path will break the PrefixStrip logic. Traefik doesn't modify your html at all.

Comment: Ok thanks you for your answer, so emby use relative paths and pydio, nextcloud or adminer use absolute, I understand. I think it is possible traefik can reroute all request to the right app with the current path

Comment: If you can't control the path, then you'll need to use Host based routing. Or you can use "PathPrefix" without a strip if you know all the possible paths that can be used.